# condition 'klass' not met when loading my page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I start my app on iPhone with a synchronized mac with visual studio 2019, I get the error :

```
error: * Assertion at ../../../../../mono/metadata/class-init.c:4109, condition `klass' not met
```

I assume it is related to my page because it crashes at the `MainPage = new myPage();` in App.cs.

I can add the whole error print if required.

Any help ?

**Edit : a few more informations about the code :**

The page's constructor does the following :

- `InitializeComponent();`
- A database call using `WebRequest`, `StreamWriter`, `WebResponse`
- Uses `JObject` to parse the anwser and update some Label
- Add `Grid` to my `Layout` : The `Grid` is using :
        `AbsoluteLayout`, `StackLayout`, `Frame`, `TapGestureRecognizer`, `Image`, `Button`, `Label`

The xaml :

```
 <ContentPage.Content>   
        <StackLayout x:Name="stackMainWrapper"
                     BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stackPageHeader"
                         Padding="20,10,20,0" >
                <StackLayout x:Name="stackHeaderNavigation"
                             Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <myApp:SvgIcon x:Name="svgBtnUser" 
                                         ResourceId="myApp.assets.icons.svg.menu.svg" 
                                         WidthRequest="25"
                                         Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <myApp:SvgIcon.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoToMenu" />
                        </myApp:SvgIcon.GestureRecognizers>
                    </myApp:SvgIcon>
                    <Label x:Name="labelPageName" 
                               Text=""
                               Style="{StaticResource TitleLabelStyle}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Button x:Name="btncreate"
                            Text=""
                            Style="{StaticResource ButtonRegularBlue}"
                            Margin="0,10"
                            Clicked=""
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    <myApp:SvgIcon x:Name="svgBtnFilterResults" 
                                         ResourceId="myApp.assets.icons.svg.search.svg" 
                                         WidthRequest="25"
                                         Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                         CornerRadius="50"
                                         Padding="10,0"
                                         IsVisible="False"
                                         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGreyStyled}"
                                         HorizontalOptions="End"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <myApp:SvgIcon.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
Tapped="BtnFilterResults_Clicked" />
                        </myApp:SvgIcon.GestureRecognizers>
                    </myApp:SvgIcon>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
            <controls:ShadowLine />

            <ScrollView x:Name="scrollPageBody"
                        Margin="0">
                <StackLayout x:Name="PageBody"
                         Padding="20" >
                    <Label x:Name="" 
                       Text=""
                       Style="{StaticResource RegularLabelStyle}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Edit : Adding the exception trace :**

> 2019-06-13 11:25:52.743 myapp.iOS[682:181626] error: * Assertion at
>   ../../../../../mono/metadata/class-init.c:4109, condition `klass' not
>   met
>
> =================================================================     Native Crash Reporting
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.
>
> =================================================================     Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
>   ================================================================= Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1d3bb20dc):0x1d3bb20cc  fd
>   7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 10  29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .{...._..)......
>
> 0x1d3bb20dc  c3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 55 d6  ff 97 
>   ...T.{......U...
>
> 0x1d3bb20ec  bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 90 29 80  d2 
>   .....{.. .._..).. 0x1d3bb20fc  01 10 00 d4 c3 00 00  54 fd 7b bf a9 fd
>   03 00 91  .......T.{.... ..
>
> =================================================================     Native stacktrace:
>   =================================================================     0x1005752fc -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x10056bc1c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1d3c259ec - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib :
>       0x1d3c2b094 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib :
>       0x1d3b0bea8 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
>     0x1006f1c7c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type  0x1006d2018 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1006d20a4 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1005adc78 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x100713638 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_ L'exécution de l'application est terminée.
>   localized_string_format_9     0x100710edc -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100702b78 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100706ad8 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100706ad8 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100703a80 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100701e50 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x10057c294 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Applic
>   ation/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS :
>   mono_pmip     0x10061794c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x10061af84 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x10047904c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x100479844 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x2007d0594 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>    Échec de l'arrêt de l'application : An error occurred on
>   client IDB1610517 while executing a reply for topic
>   xvs/idb/16.1.0.517/stop-app   0x2007d5d20 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x2000992dc -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>    L'exécution de l'application est terminée.     0x2000a1874 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x200098f60 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x200099850 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x200097b9c -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x200097864 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x20009c3a4 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x20009d188 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>   _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext  0x20009c25c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x2007cee30 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x2000a0f5c -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x2007d4328 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x2003d0ba8 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x1d69909fc -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d699a40c -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d6999c14 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d3a557d4 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>       0x1d39fa5d8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>       0x1d69cb040 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d69cacdc -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d69cb294 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
>   :   0x1d3fa7018 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x1d3fa6f98 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x1d3fa6880 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x1d3fa17bc -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x1d3fa10b0 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific  0x1d61a179c -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   : GSEventRunModal     0x2007d7978 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>   UIApplicationMain     0x10071128c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x10070343c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100703a80 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100703a80 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100703a80 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100703a80 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x100701e50 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x10057c294 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x10061794c -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/enVisit
>   4>      at  <0xffffffff>       at
>   UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x000bc>     at
>   UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x0002a>      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main
>   <0x0006a>       at myapp.iOS.Application:Main <0x00016>     at
>   :runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00082>
>   ================================================================= e360.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : mono_pmip  0x10061cf68 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x100560c64 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x100700be0 -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : xamarin_localized_string_format_9   0x10052adfc -
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B332FB94-B5DA-4627-8D03-5471B0CE66FC/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1d3a668e0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib :
>
> =================================================================     Managed Stacktrace:
>   =================================================================       at  <0xffffffff>       at myapp.App:.ctor <0x0002c>    at
>   myapp.iOS.AppDelegate:FinishedLaunching <0x0006e>       at
>   :runtime_invoke_direct_bool__this___UIApplication_NSDictionary
>   <0x000b

Comment: Could you please share the code with us so we can see what is wrong

Comment: I can't share the code since it is related to work, but I can share every nugets used and inits added in the AppDelegate.cs, every references and nuget used and which ones are used on myPage.

Comment: Could you remove all work sensitive material and share it?  Also, was the code working and then it suddenly stopped? What changes were made after which it stopped?

Comment: If I do this, the page will be empty, this is why I can't share. I know it's getting harder to understand without code, therefore, I can tell everything the page is doing (roughly). Before, I had an AOT issue, and just fixed it today, this is the first time I've went this far. I've always built on Android so far, and everything works there.

Comment: Oh so you were building a solution but you were never able to test it on an iOS device. So now when you did, it gives you that error. Could you try to create a new solution and move the files over?

Comment: Okay, I try this. I added a few informations about the code (I hope I removed everything related to work e_e )

Comment: could try to create an "Exception Catchpoint" (Run->New Exception Catchpoint) and share the exception that is caught?

Comment: @SamuelL. Hi, have you sholved this problem? If no more code in project , you can find out where the cause is by setting a breakpoint.

Comment: @Saamer I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Saamer I have the exception trace, I'll share it, but I can't find anything such as Exception Catchpoint actually... Junior Jiang - MSFT I can add a break point on the line, and then try to get inside with F11, but it crashs the moment I press F11, I can't get inside the constructor to see what line is crashing.

Comment: @SamuelL. on VS for Windows, you basically go to the "Exception Settings" window and select to catch all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", and you could also place a try-catch around the line causing the crash to see what exception is being raised

Comment: @Saamer I found the problem, but thanks for your help. I will certainly try this to know the exact raised exception, and give you my feedback on it.

Comment: @Saamer The common language runtime excpetions is checked by default. Therefore, I still cant get the exception in the try catch, although I know how to make it happen. It just crashes the app and give the trace I shared on Edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to take apart the crashing code, and by uncommenting line after line to see what is breaking, apparently, using `dynamic` on Xamarin iOS make the app crash.

So well.. avoid using `dynamic` I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the page before assigning to mainPage.

```
MainPage = new myPage();
```

Comment: Yes I know, just a missing word, sorry ! I'm editing my question.